# Laravel 5.2 - Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

This question has [already been asked many times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Integrity%20constraint%20violation%3A%201452%20Cannot%20add%20or%20update%20a%20child%20row%3A%20a%20foreign%20key%20constraint%20fails), I went through all the answers, but none solves the error I'm getting.

I'm using Laravel 5.2

I have 2 tables - Classifieds and Categories. When I want to create a classified, I get the error message:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`myclassified`.`classifieds`, CONSTRAINT `classifieds_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`))

Migration files defined like this:

for `classifieds` table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('classifieds', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->string('price');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('classifieds');
}
```

for `categories` table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('categories');
}
```

and to add the foreign key,

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::table('classifieds', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('classifieds', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('classifieds_category_id_foreign');
    });
}
```

The Models are:

`Classified` model:

```
class Classified extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'classifieds';

   protected $fillable = ['title', 'category_id', 'description', 'price'];

   protected $hidden = [];

   public function category(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');

   }
}
```

and the `Category` model:

```
class Category extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'categories';
   protected $fillable = ['name'];

   protected $hidden = [];

   public function classifieds(){
       return $this->hasMany('App\Classified');
   }
}
```

and the store method in controller is defined like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $title = $request->input('title');
    $category_id = $request->input('category_id');
    $description = $request->input('description');
    $price = $request->input('price');

    Classified::create([
            'title' =>  $this->title,
            'category_id' => $this->category_id,
            'description' => $this->description,
            'price' => $this->price
    ]);

    return \Redirect::route('classifieds.index')
        ->with('message', 'Ad created');
}
```

What is my mistake in database set up?

Answer (score 0):

This happens, when you are trying to save `Classified` and assign the foreign key with an id of category that does not exist yet in `Category` table.

If you don't have the foreign ID yet, just leave it to be null and make sure you do this on migration to allow null values;

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::table('classifieds', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('set null');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('classifieds', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('classifieds_category_id_foreign');
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi. I'm still getting same `Integrity constraint violation` error:  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`myclassified`.`classifieds`, CONSTRAINT `classifieds_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL)

Comment: Did you run the migration again?

Comment: @byteseeker I was wrong. I don't think you can add foreign key id that is not exist